# Making `too many arguments in call to function` an error in Clang

Tags: c, clang, c89

I am trying to make the compiler warning `warning: too many arguments in call to 'IF'` an error (where `IF` is a function).

I am having trouble configuring clang, as I cannot figure out the actual name of the warning.

I tried the following:

```
clang -Werror=too-many-arguments main.c

warning: unknown warning option '-Werror=too-many-arguments'; did you mean '-Werror=unknown-argument'?
  [-Wunknown-warning-option]
```

But that just produces the warning above.

With

```
clang -Werror main.c
```

The warning does become an error, but I am trying to make only this specific warning an error.

How do I find the name of this compiler warning so I can promote it to a compiler error?

Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I think it's the opposite to what OP is asking about...

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I am trying to promote the warning to an error.

Comment: Use `-Werror` and fix any other issues that prevent your code compiling with that.  I️ use it “all” the time.  I️ very seldom run any of my own code that doesn’t compile cleanly under `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, and I️ usually have some more warnings enabled.  Beware: `-Weverything` is too fussy.

Comment: It would improve the question to post a sample program which produces the warning in question, so that others can test out their answers

Comment: `void test()` is an old-style function declaration. It doesn't specify how many or what type of arguments the function expects. The solution is to use a prototype: `void test(void)`, to specify that the function takes no arguments. Why exactly don't you want to specify `void`?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: `void test()` is not a prototype.

Comment: @KeithThompson there was no code in the original question.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I request that you re-open this question, or kindly ask you to explain yourselves how the given reason for closure applies to this question. The question is/was very clear, since the first edit. Maybe the error was too alien to you, but the question is/was properly tagged with `clang`. The compiler's warning message is very clear, and doesn't beg for any code-example for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the current sources in Subversion and found this: `test/Misc/warning-flags.c` in the Clang sources list `warn_call_wrong_number_of_arguments` (the internal code for this warning), which means that that it is expected that this warning has no separate `-W` flag. I'm sure the Clang developers would accept a patch which introduces an explicit name for this option.

But until that, `-Werror` is your only option.

Answer (score 1):

`-Werror` is turning *all* warnings into errors. You could turn off all warnings except for that particular one you are interested in, but that is wrong on so many levels, I mention it only for academic reasons.

You might also consider getting a good lint, such as Gimpel's FlexeLint product. This is a lint with completely configurable warnings, errors and informational messages.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer your question, but I believe I can provide a better solution than what you're looking for.

This:

```
void test () {
  printf("test\n");
}
```

is an old-style non-prototype function definition. As a definition, it specifies that the function has no parameters, but as a declaration, it does not specify the number and types of any expected arguments. Given this definition, a call that incorrectly passes an argument, like `test("test")` or `test(42)`, is not a constraint violation and does not require a diagnostic, even though such a call has undefined behavior if it's evaluated.

clang is going above and beyond the language requirements to warn you about the incorrect call. (I'm mildly surprised it does so. gcc, for example, does not.)

This kind of thing is exactly why prototypes were added to the language back in 1989. As you mention in the question, you can define the function like this:

```
void test(void) {
   printf("test\n");
}
```

Given that this definition is visible, a conforming compiler must diagnose any attempt to call this function incorrectly with one or more arguments.

The solution to your problem is not to coax the compiler into diagnosing a problem that the language doesn't require it to diagnose. It's to fix the code. There is very rarely a good reason *not* to use prototypes for all function declarations and definitions.

Old-style declarations and definitions are *obsolescent*, but they're still legal even in the 2011 version of ISO C. (I personally consider this unfortunate.)

(You say you don't want to specify `void` as a parameter, but you haven't explained why.)

Comment: The question is asking how to make clang regard your first example as an error.

Comment: @cdignam: Yes, I know that, and I explicitly acknowledged it. I'm offering a better solution to the underlying problem.